# WMI filter missing from GPRESULT on Win 10 clients but not Win 7 clients

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, wmi, windows-10, windows-sbs-2011

I am having a problem with a new Windows 10 WMI filter I have created on a Windows SBS2011 server, I created it in the WMI section alongside my working filters:

Namespace: root\CIMV2

Query: select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Version like "10.%"

On my Win 10 clients when running GPUPDATE /force and then GPRESULT /h this WMI filter does not appear, all of the others do whether they apply to that client OS or not (labelled true/false accordingly). I performed a clean Win 10 install yesterday, connected to the domain and it still doesn't appear, on a Win 7 client the filter appears correctly.

The odd thing is I have 5 WMI filters on the server:

- Windows SBS Client
- Windows SBS Client - Windows 10
- Windows SBS Client - Windows 7/8/10
- Windows SBS Client - Windows 8
- Windows SBS Client - Windows XP
  (we have no Windows XP/Vista/8 clients)

On the server GPRESULT shows:

Windows SBS Client

Windows SBS Client - Windows 10

Windows SBS Client - Windows 7/8/10

On the client it shows:

Windows SBS Client

Windows SBS Client - Windows 7/8/10

Windows SBS Client - Windows 8

Windows SBS Client - Windows XP

Using WBEMTEST on the client and the query in my original post there are no results returned, when using my Win 7/8/10 query a result is returned. Likewise if I run WBEMTEST on the server and use the Windows 8 query no result is returned.

Rather confusing so I hope someone can help me work out what is going on. Thanks in advance

Comment: What GPO is the filter linked to, and where is the GPO linked?

Comment: I created a new GPO to add a registry key in Win 10 clients to enable verbose login messages as the SBS2011 option for this does not appear to work on Win 10 clients even when they are included in the working Win 7/8/10 WMI filter. The GPO is then linked to the SBSUsers OU which is where all users are located.

Comment: Are there any Windows 10 computers in the "SBSUsers" OU? If not, that is the problem. The GPO needs to be linked at a location that would be in-scope for the Windows 10 computers.

Comment: Thanks Greg, after your first reply I looked at my OU tree and found the general policies for the other OS's had been linked to a different OU (SBSComputers) so I then created a new GPO as default policy for my Win 10 filter and applied that to the WMI and linked to the SBSComputers section. I just need to test this is now working but I am still confused why Win 7 clients correctly displayed the WMI in GPRESULT. I will post back the results asap.

Comment: I have tested this now by forcing gpupdate, rebooting and the result still misses the WMI filter. I confirmed that gpresult shows the computer is part of the SBSComputers OU where I linked it to. I haven't rebooted the server yet so will try that when I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it, it was a mistake on my part. I had been linking my GPOs to the Users OU as I was used to but these particular GPOs had settings made in the Computer policies so should have been linked to the Computers OU. Once I linked them here they appeared in GPRESULT. Odd that Win 7 clients showed the WMI filter correctly before doing this but seems to be working now.